# Switch between different JPanels in one JFrame without CardLayout-buttons

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, panel, frame

I'm new at Java GUI and I'm trying to make a program that shows a login screen and once logged in, a menu. 
What I am looking for is a way to navigate through different JPanels in just one JFrame. To navigate the user should use buttons located inside these panels.

I use Netbeans to do this. The furthest I got is to open one JPanel in a JFrame, I've been trying to close one and open another but it won't work because the current panel stays open.

The reason I do not want to use the CardLayout is because I do not wish to have to tabs visible. I don't think you can hide them...

I hope you guy's can help me out,

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CardLayout does exactly what you want and absolutely does not require you to use tabs.  In fact, the java tutorial on [card layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) provides a demo that uses a combobox to change between different cards.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow! but might you know if it is possible to remove any kind of 'global list of the cards', in tabs or combobox? So that, in my program, you can go from login "card" to just 1 card through the use of a button.

Comment: Programming is so damn addictive xD It's working like a charm!!

Comment: @Vaporware Sounds like you got it working but just in case - no, you do not need to maintain a list of cards.  You can navigate through the cards either by using the show method to show a specific card(by name) or sequentially by use of next and previous.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to implement a [wizard](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) or similar. Take a look at the linked article.

Answer (score -2):

Simply remove the panel from the `contentPane` and add the new you want to show. This have to be done by code when the button is pressed and all it's ok to change to the next panel.

Comment: Uggh.. The blind, leading the blind.  Please refrain from giving more advice on dynamic GUIs until you gain a great deal more experience.  The CardLayout is the perfect way to go on this.  While components *can* be swapped out at run-time, they are generally not on the content pane, and more needs to be done to ensure the new layout is properly validated.